# Overriding special operator using MACROLET?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to override IF locally (the purpose is to embed a DSL).

The behavior really confuses me. In SBCL:

```
(macrolet ((if (x) x)) 
  (if 'x)) ; => X

(macrolet ((if (x) x)) 
  (let ((x 2)) 
    (if 'x))) ; => Execution of a form compiled with errors.

(let ((x 2)) 
  (macrolet ((if (x) x)) 
    (if 'x))) ; => Execution of a form compiled with errors.
```

Any idea on why it behaves like that?

I also tried using an interned symbol `xxx::if` but with no luck, SBCL still think it's an special operator whatever package it's in.

Is there anyway to correctly override a special operator locally? Or at least literally override, which means one can type in `if` and it gets expanded (using some reader magic might help but I'm not familiar with that).

Update (Solved):
The exact error message for the 2nd I were getting

```
Execution of a form compiled with errors.
Form:
  (MACROLET ((IF (X)
             X))
  (IF 'X))
Compile-time error:
  Lock on package COMMON-LISP violated when binding IF as a local macro while in
package COMMON-LISP-USER.
See also:
  The SBCL Manual, Node "Package Locks"
  The ANSI Standard, Section 11.1.2.1.2
   [Condition of type SB-INT:COMPILED-PROGRAM-ERROR]
```

3rd is similar.

It turns out that using `xxx::if` makes it work. I was just not correctly shadowing the symbol in the previous experiment.

Simple way to make it work:

```
(defpackage p)
(macrolet ((p::if (x) x)) 
  (let ((x 2)) 
    (p::if 'x))) ; => X
```

If you want to inherit other usual CL operators in `P` then just do `(defpackage p (:use :cl) (:shadow if))`.

Comment: I get an error from the first one, "Lock on package COMMON-LISP violated when binding IF as a local macro"

Comment: If I use `p::if` I get no errors from the 2nd and 3rd version, just warnings about the unused variable X. Which is understandable because you're quoting `x` in the body, not using the variable.

Comment: They both return `2` with no warnings if I remove the quote before `x`.

Comment: Ok that's interesting, previously I did `sb-ext:unlock-package :cl`. Probably some interference with package locking? Let me try with a fresh REPL.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error when I run `(let ((x 2)) (macrolet ((cl-user::if (x) x)) (cl-user::if 'x)))` in a fresh repl. I'm on SBCL 1.5.1. Is this implementation dependent?

Comment: Don't use `cl-user::if`, create your own package and use `mypackage::if`

Comment: Ok
`(defpackage p (:use :cl) (:shadow if)) (macrolet ((p::if (x) x)) (p::if 'x))`
works for me now. Many thanks!

Comment: I just did `(make-package 'p)` and then I used `p::if`. No need to inherit or shadow anything.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the exact error message you got.

Comment: Sure, I also want to use some other CL provided stuff in the DSL (that's why I want to embed it).
Ok I'm updating the question now.

Comment: Notice that `(defpackage p)` and `(make-package 'p)` are underspecified for portable Common Lisp. It's undefined which packages they are *using*. SBCL notoriously *uses* none.

Answer (score 0):

Binding the `if` symbol (the one in the Common Lisp package, `common-lisp:if`) is [undefined behavior](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_abab.htm).

If you want to create a macro language which uses some of the same symbol names as standard Common Lisp, it's best to use a different package, so that what looks like `if` is actually `mypackage:if`.

More detail: section 11.1.2.1.2 states that all binding of symbols of the Common Lisp package is undefined behavior **except where explicitly allowed**.

Binding a Common Lisp symbol with `macrolet` is explicitly allowed in subclause [11.1.2.1.2.1](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_ababa.htm):

*"If an external symbol of the COMMON-LISP package is not defined as a standardized function, macro, or special operator, it is allowed to lexically bind it as a macro (e.g., with macrolet).*

So, for instance, because the constant `pi` (i.e. `cl:pi`) isn't a function, macro or special operator, `(macrolet ((pi ...)) ...)` can be evaluated by a conforming program.